# Correct way of declaring a pointer with value

Tags: c, pointers

I want to learn very basics of pointers in C language

What is the difference between below two ways? Which is correct? Which is more preferable?

```
int a = 20;
int *p = &a ;
```

or

```
int a = 20;
int *p ;
p = &a ;
```

Comment: They're both correct. They produce the same effect. Which one is preferable is a matter of style.

Comment: 1. Both are correct 2. It depends.

Comment: This issue applies to any variable types, not just pointers.  For example, `int a = 20;` vs. `int a; a = 20;`  The iniitializer combines the declaration with the assignment, while splitting it apart separates them.

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is not related to pointers, but to declaring and initializing variables in general.

For example, you can do:

```
int a; // this declares the variable a as an integer
a = 20; // this initializes the variable a with the value 20.
```

OR, you can combine these two into one line:

```
int a = 20;  //this now both declares and initializes the variable a.
```

The difference is that you can only declare a variable ONCE, but you can assign a value to it as many times as you like.

So if you were to write

```
int a = 20;
```

and then later on in your code you wanted to change the value of a to say, 30, here you can ONLY write

```
a = 30;
```

You could not write `int a = 30;` again, because you cannot declare a again, a has already been declared.

This difference is what you are illustrating with your pointers.

```
int a = 20;  //variable a is declared as an int and also initialized to the value 20
int *p = &a ; //pointer p is declared and initialized with the address of a.
or
int a = 20; // variable a is declared as an int and also initialized to the value of 20
int *p ; // pointer p is declared
p = &a ; // pointer p is assigned the value that is the address of variable a.
```

You could also have written

```
int a;
a = 20;
int *p;
p = &a;
```

And this is still correct, and produces exactly the same result.

Comment: Re “you can only declare a variable ONCE”: You can only **define** a variable once. In various circumstances, you can declare a variable many times. For example, at global scope, you may have `int a; extern int a; extern int a; extern int a;`. For objects, a definition is a declaration that causes space to be reserved for the object.